# Forced authorship questions

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

This question:

[What a PhD student should do when their supervisor orders them to have a name on their paper just because of grant purposes?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108956/what-a-phd-student-should-do-when-their-supervisor-orders-them-to-have-a-name-on)

seems very related to

[What should PhD students do when they are told to add authors who did not contribute to the paper (e.g., head of school, international funders)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64730/what-should-phd-students-do-when-they-are-told-to-add-authors-who-did-not-contri)

and

[My advisor wants me to include a name of someone who has no contribution to the paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20899/my-advisor-wants-me-to-include-a-name-of-someone-who-has-no-contribution-to-the)

We also have the question asked from the other side of the table

[How to explain to a student that it is common to include a supervisor as a co-author](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54874/how-to-explain-to-a-student-that-it-is-common-to-include-a-supervisor-as-a-co-au)

I also asked something in a more canonical sense (I think)

[What are the minimum contributions required for co-authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/what-are-the-minimum-contributions-required-for-co-authorship)

but it misses the interpersonal aspects of what can happen if a junior person refuses the request/demand of a senior person. Do we want a canonical question to cover these topics that would include a list of links to authorship guidelines for different fields/journals and a summary of those statements as well as a summary of the repercussions that can arise out of saying no and a strategy for dealing with the whole situation?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be better to include a list of "related questions" in the body of the respective questions. Otherwise, too much existing work will need to be merged (a very messy operation, given that all the questions are slightly different).

Comment: This sounds like a situation calling out for a tag creation!  Perhaps "forced-authorship"?